# Create a new derived column in pandas if value inside the column is non-null

Tags: python, pandas

My input data like this

```
SL.NO   Name
1      KING  BATA
2   
3   
4     AGS
5     FORMULA GROWTH 
6   
7     Bag
```

Output

```
SL.NO   Name               Value
1     KING  BATA          Present
2                         Not Present
3                         Not Present
4   AGS                   Present
5   FORMULA GROWTH       Present
6                        Not Present
7   Bag                  Present
```

How to handle null, blank  and junk values in pandas?

Comment: Please accept one solution and stick to it. Thanks :-) Accept my solution only if you are using it. Otherwise, not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
#If missing value is NaN
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Name'].isnull(), 'Present', 'Not Present')
```

Or:

```
#If missing value is empty string
df['Value'] = np.where(df['Name'].eq(''), 'Present', 'Not Present')
```

Comment: can i add multiple conditions  in numpy.where, to remove values which are only numeric.

Comment: Ok, then why another solution working? I am confused

Comment: I am just asking. Can i add multiple conditions together.

Comment: Yes, need only `df['Name'].isnull() & (df[Name].apply(type) == str)`

Comment: Because there are possible 2 states - numebrs saved as strings or mixed types - some values are strings and some ints (floats)- NaN are floats too. For check it need `print (df[Name].apply(type))`

Answer (score 2):

Fun with `pd.Categorical`:

```
df

   SL.NO            Name
0      1       KING BATA
1      2                
2      3                
3      4             AGS
4      5  FORMULA GROWTH
5      6                
6      7             Bag

df['Value'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(df.Name.astype(bool),
                              categories=['Not Present', 'Present'])
df

   SL.NO            Name        Value
0      1       KING BATA      Present
1      2                  Not Present
2      3                  Not Present
3      4             AGS      Present
4      5  FORMULA GROWTH      Present
5      6                  Not Present
6      7             Bag      Present
```

Which, incidentally, works regardless of whether your missing values are `NaN`s, `None`, or `''`, because `astype(bool)` takes advantage of the false-yness of these values:

```
df

   SL.NO            Name        Value
0      1       KING BATA      Present
1      2            None  Not Present
2      3            None  Not Present
3      4             AGS      Present
4      5  FORMULA GROWTH      Present
5      6            None  Not Present
6      7             Bag      Present
```