# Create a new column based on NaN values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with column **A**:

| A |
| --- |
| 5 |
| 1 |
| NaN |
| 12 |
| 13 |
| NaN |
| NaN |

how can I create a new column **B** based on **A** to give True if the value is known and False if the value is NaN with an output like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | True |
| 1 | True |
| NaN | False |
| 12 | True |
| 13 | True |
| NaN | False |
| NaN | False |

Thanks

Comment: [`pandas.Series.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html#pandas.Series.notna)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a new derived column in pandas if value inside the column is non-null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929780/create-a-new-derived-column-in-pandas-if-value-inside-the-column-is-non-null)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html):

```
df['B'] = df['A'].notna()
```

output:

```
      A      B
0   5.0   True
1   1.0   True
2   NaN  False
3  12.0   True
4  13.0   True
5   NaN  False
6   NaN  False
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `.isna()` (or `.isnull()`) method to determine if the value is `Nan`. It returns `True` for `Nan` and `False` for the rest, so we need to negate that. Negation is done with `~` operator.

```py
df['B'] = ~df['A'].isna()
```

Comment: or [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) to avoid negation ;)